# Is yellow fever vaccination required for travel to Ireland?

Tags: india, health, turkey, ireland, yellow-fever

I am planning to fly from Delhi to Dubli-Ireland , transit at Istanbul

Do I need Yellow Fever Vaccination?

Brgds
Shahid Hasan

Answer (score 2):

**No**, you don't, because [Ireland and Turkey do not have a yellow fever vaccination requirement](https://www.who.int/ith/ITH_country_list.pdf?ua=1).

Even in countries that do, yellow fever vaccination is required only if you're coming from an [area with endemic yellow fever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yellow_fever#Epidemiology), which covers much of South America and Africa, but not India or Turkey.